# Discord JS Error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Trying to make a system where, when you say a blacklisted word, it deletes it and goes DMs the person to tell him which channel it got deleted, the reason why and the message that he said. But my code keeps telling me this:

```
2020-02-25T02:05:30.557281+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
2020-02-25T02:05:30.557293+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:85:15
2020-02-25T02:05:30.557294+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21
2020-02-25T02:05:30.557295+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2020-02-25T02:05:30.557358+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 6)
```

And here is my code :

```
bot.on('message', async message => {

  var sender = message.author
  var channel = message.channel.id

  if(sender.id === 'BOT ID') {
    return;
    }


if(message.content.includes('discord.gg/')) {
      message.delete();
      message.author.send(`**Your message in <#${channel}> had been deleted.**  
      \n**__Reason:__** *Promotion*
      \n**__Your Message:__** *${message.content}*`)
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User can not allow to send him DM message from this server. Better dont use `try - catch` constrution. Method [DM Channel send](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=send) return a [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) of message if message recive success and reject err if somethink went wrong. You can handle it with single block `.catch(err => )`

```
if(message.content.includes('discord.gg/')) {
      message.delete();
      message.author.send(`**Your message in <#${channel}> had been deleted.**  
      \n**__Reason:__** *Promotion*
      \n**__Your Message:__** *${message.content}*`).catch(err => console.log('User don`t allow to send DM message from him'))
  }
```

Comment: Since he uses an async function, I kinda expected him to use `await`, where try catch makes total sense to use.

Comment: await for what ? He don`t try to constant result of callback function to variabale.

Comment: Hm? You dont have to use await only for that purpose. You can just use `await message.author.send()`. Normally it isnt good practise to mix promise based code and await, so depending on the rest of the code, its totally viable to use await.

Comment: So how its solved his problem? its just stop his code execute for await a promise reject or resolve

Comment: It was just an alternative, since you said better NOT to use try - catch, although it's, depending on the code, equally viable.

Comment: In my opinion, catching `promise reject` through the `try` `catch` construct is not the best solution. At a minimum, this adds extra nesting to the code where it was possible to add 1 line of code.

Answer (score 0):

This user probably doesn't allow DM's from this server. You can basically deny that other users DM you from specific servers. To avoid the error showing up, you need to use a `try catch` block and handle it accordingly.